# smartGWT onDraw when is it executed?

Tags: notifications, smartgwt, ondraw, puremvc

When is executed the onDraw method of a DynamicForm exactly?

When I first load my page (a puremvc.Mediator page) and draw my DynamicForm with an onDraw method, I enter in this onDraw method. Then I destroy the view component, remove the Mediator from the Facade, and re-load the page. DynamicForm is being created again, the viewComponent too, but I don't enter in the onDraw method. Just as if the object has already been drawn! But the thing is it was destroyed, its parent too, and the parent of the parent, too.
What could be the problem?

Comment: To be more specific:
I have a Tab with VLayout A, in which I put VLayout B, in which I put DynamicForm C via addMember() method. In C I have the onDraw method. I load the page and it's OK, then destroy it (destroy A, B and C) and the whole Tab too. Then reload the page (recreation of A, B and C), C is again being added to B via addMember() method, but is obviously not drawn?! Why? Is there something in the cache? Does the browser "think" it's already been drawn and if yes, why? How can I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got it.

The thing is that I use PUREMVC Mediator and Notification. On the first load, everything's good as the async method that returns data for DynamicForm C is sending the successful notification AFTER I have already created the VLayout B, and thus the addMember method adds and displays the DynamicForm C.

On the second load, I use the data that has already been gathered from DB, so no async method is being processed and the notification arrives BEFORE I create VLayout B, so basically the DynamicForm C is NOT being drawn.

My solution : I reordered some lines of code to make sure I always call the method that sends data via Notification (whether from DB or stocked) AFTER of the page creation.